# How to properly name a file downloaded using webview?

Tags: android, webview

The download works properly but it named as download how can i name it as the same as filename ?

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                    //for downloading directly through download manager
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "downloads");
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    dm.enqueue(request);

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {       

public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                long contentLength) {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                Uri.parse(url));

        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Name of your downloadble file goes here, example: Mathematics II ");
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT); //This is important!
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE); //CATEGORY.OPENABLE
        intent.setType("*/*");//any application,any extension
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: is there any way to get the same name of the file?

Comment: final String[] separated = url.split("/");
final String myFile = separated[separated.length - 1]; and then request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, myFile);

Comment: it gives me attachment.php name

Comment: those are torrent files and stired as attachments is there anyother way to get the file name?